# How to style DataGridCell in WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have datagrid with the hierarchy like this..

[image: WPF]

I want to style textblock in datagrid to have horizontal alignment to Center like picture above.

Can you help me How I can achieve this? With WPF Styling?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DataGridTemplateColumn.

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Key">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Key}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: what is `Key` here? I'm still confuse

Comment: In my code I used an dictionary as the DataSource. Header ist the name of your column that will be displayed. Text Key is the property of your object the columm will be bound to.

Comment: I have many columns approx 25 columns.. Am I used all this to declare one by one? Can I used Style instead of using this approach?

Comment: Yes you could use a style. But in that style you have to define the template I think too. Of course that would be a better solution because you dont have to duplicate the code.